# how to prevent automatically adding mailto attribute

Tags: tinymce, mailto

When I write an email address (test@test.com) tinymce automatically adds a mailto link :

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</ a>
```

Is there a way to remove this feature and keep it only for site addresses - for example - `www.test.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is due to the `autolink` plugin.  You can set the regex that the plugin should use for matching links by using the `autolink_pattern` setting.

The default value for this setting (as of TinyMCE 4.6.5) is:

```
var AutoLinkPattern = 
/^(https?:\/\/|ssh:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|file:\/|www\.|(?:mailto:)?[A-Z0-9._%+\-]+@)(.+)$/i;
```

(you can see this in the source code for the autolink plugin).

Try putting this in your configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea'
  ...
  ...
  autolink_pattern: /^(https?:\/\/|ssh:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|file:\/|www\.)(.+)$/i,
});
```

In my testing this still converts URLs but does not convert email addresses.